# Cannot read property 'data' of undefined discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

Making a command to take a random photo of a waifu in this case, and posting it in the channel

Code here:

```
  if (command === 'waifu') {
        const waifu = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        got('https://waifu.pics/api/sfw/waifu').then(response => {
            let content = JSON.parse(response.body);
            let waifuUrl = content[0].data.children[0].data.url;
            let waifuImage = content[0].data.children[0].data.url;
            waifu.setImage(`${waifuImage}`)
            waifu.setURL(`${waifuUrl}`)
            waifu.setColor('#ffb9f4')
            waifu.setFooter(`Requested by ${message.author.user}`)
            waifu.setTimestamp()
            waifu.setAuthor(`waifu.pics`, `https://waifu.pics/`)
            message.channel.send(waifu)
        });
    };
```

The API should be correct. After a few small changes, I tried console logging the JSON and it did output the correct thing. But when running the code in discord, it outputted a  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined` error. I cannot seem to figure out the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 if (command === 'waifu') {
      const waifu = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      get('https://waifu.pics/api/sfw/waifu').then(response => {
          let content = response.body;
          let waifuUrl = content.url;
          let waifuImage = content.url;
          waifu.setImage(`${waifuImage}`)
          waifu.setURL(`${waifuUrl}`)
          waifu.setColor('#ffb9f4')
          waifu.setFooter(`Requested by ${message.author.username}`)
          waifu.setTimestamp()
          waifu.setAuthor(`waifu.pics`, `https://waifu.pics/`)
          message.channel.send(waifu)
        });
    };
```

You thought a little bit complicated ^^ You had something with `children` and `data`, although the API just gives an URL. You don't even have to parse it. And you have used the function `got()`, which you have to replace with `get()`.

I fixed your code just copy it from above.